# PUPhotoPickerHostViewController viewServiceDidTerminateWithError

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I have theses classes to get the user to pick an image from his/her photo library.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var activeFullCover: ActiveFullCover?
    @State var inputImage: UIImage = UIImage()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            activeFullCover = .imagePicker
        }, label: {
            Text("Get image")
        })
            .sheet(item: $activeFullCover) { _ in
                ImagePickerRaw(selectedImage: $inputImage)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .onDisappear {
                        loadImage()
                    }
            }
    }
    
    
    func loadImage() {
        print("Loading image")
    }
    
    enum ActiveFullCover: Identifiable, Equatable {
        case imagePicker
        case addGroupMember
        
        public var id: String {
            switch self {
            case .imagePicker:
                return "imagePicker"
            case .addGroupMember:
                return "addGroupMember"
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ImagePickerRaw: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary
    @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerRaw>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return imagePicker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerRaw>) {
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        
        var parent: ImagePickerRaw?
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePickerRaw) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            
            if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage,
               let parent = parent {
                parent.selectedImage = image
            }
            
            parent?.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            parent = nil
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that after opening the sheet a couple of times (around 30). The ram usage keeps increasing. After the 32 times I tried, the sheet opens up for a second then instantly closes. The log gets filled up with these error messages.

```
2022-05-05 17:39:54.005531+0300 ImagePickerDemo[975:346447] [lifecycle] [u 9598FD0E-E868-4FFB-8A1E-492BAB1C364B:m (null)] [com.apple.mobileslideshow.photo-picker(1.0)] Connection to plugin invalidated while in use.

2022-05-05 17:39:54.016548+0300 ImagePickerDemo[975:346269] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}

2022-05-05 17:39:54.016741+0300 ImagePickerDemo[975:346269] [UI] -[PUPhotoPickerHostViewController viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:] Error Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}

2022-05-05 17:39:54.016941+0300 ImagePickerDemo[975:346269] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
2022-05-05 17:39:54.017148+0300 ImagePickerDemo[975:346269] [UI] -[PUPhotoPickerHostViewController viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:] Error Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)"
```

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?